# get_user_by("slug", $userslug) fails when username contains a +

Tags: wordpress

I'm using

```
$user = get_user_by("slug", $userslug);
```

And it is working ok, but have come across a user who has a username like `the+user+name` and it's returning `bool(false)`.  Is there any way I can get around this?

```
  $userslug = basename(um_user_profile_url());
  $user = get_user_by("slug", $userslug);
  var_dump($user);
```

Comment: If you **have** to use the slug, why not pass the $userslug through [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? So `str_replace( '+', '-', $userslug )` I'm assuming the `+` is converted to `-`.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I have to as that's the only value of the user profile page available to me in the function. So then if I use -'s instead it becomes a different username and won't be found?

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $userslug )` before that line to see what's returned for that user. The `-` won't be a different user since the `+` is probably being converted to a `-` in the slug. If it's not, the `var_dump` will tell you what the slug of the user is. More importantly, what error are you getting? update your question with that information.

Comment: The value of the slug is the user name with + joining their chosen words.  It's not that its been made programmatically like that, but that they've chosen it.  I've added the error in the question!

Comment: I updated to remove information about it being an error, since as you found, it's not an error. More questions: what are you trying to do with this information? Where are you using it? Is this for the user when they are logged in? I'm wondering if there is a better way to get the information you want.

Comment: In the end I did find an alternative way to get that user ID, no solution to the code not working as it should.